# Android listview header accessibility issue

Tags: android, accessibility

When using a android listview header with accessibility (google talkback) the entire contents of the header are read.  So imagine i had a header view like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".LinearLayout" >

<Button
    android:text="BUTTON"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text 1"
    android:paddingTop="10px"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text 2"
    android:paddingTop="10px"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text 3"
    android:paddingTop="10px"/>
```

Whenever i click anything in the header ALL the textview titles get announced. so in this case if i click text 3, the system announces "TEXT 1, TEXT 2, TEXT 3".  it's automatic. How do i get it to not announce all the things just the item the user clicks on ?

here is my listview code, its just standard stuff:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android List View",
                "Adapter implementation",
                "Simple List View In Android",
                "Create List View Android",
                "Android Example",
                "List View Source Code",
                "List View Array Adapter",
                "Android Example List View"
        };

        // Define a new Adapter
        // First parameter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);


        listView.addHeaderView(header);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // ListView Clicked item index
                int itemPosition     = position;

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Show Alert
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my headerView root i set the following command good in api 16 and up to rectify the issue mostly:

```
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
```